# Add markers from firebase to google map in website

Tags: javascript, google-maps, firebase, google-maps-markers, marker

**Firebase data structure** :

[image]

I need to add markers in the google map using these latlang.

**My code** :

```
    <script>
    var map;

    function initMap() {

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 6.930274, lng: 79.861618},
          zoom: 16.5,
          panControl: false,
          gestureHandling: 'greedy',
          disableDefaultUI: true,
          disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
        });

        var dbRef= firebase.database().ref('bins');
        dbRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
            var snap = snapshot.val();
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: {lat: snap.lat, lng: snap.lang},
              map: map
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

Nothing happened when this code runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are not accessing the children of `bins` you have to use `forEach` to be able to get the values:

```
 var dbRef= firebase.database().ref('bins');
    dbRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    var childs=child.val();
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: {lat: childs.lat, lng: childs.lang},
          map: map
          });
       });
   });
```

Comment: I had to add parseFloat(). Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

check this out

use `parseFloat()` in the position because firebase return data as **strings**.

```
position: {lat: parseFloat(snap.lat), lng: parseFloat(snap.lang)}
```

Comment: Thanks and also I had to change the "value" to "child_added"
    dbRef.on('value', function(snapshot)